# List of different components in Angular 2 ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular

I know there are many similar questions and almost all of them end with DynamicComponentLoader answer but still, I think use case described below is so simple and common (IMO) that solution with Angular 2 should be straight forward.

## Sample use case

I have an array of news items with property `type` describing what kind of item it is.

```
var items = [
  { id: 1, type: 'text', data: {} },
  { id: 2, type: 'text', data: {} },
  { id: 3, type: 'text-two-columns', data: {} },
  { id: 4, type: 'image-text', data: {} },
  { id: 5, type: 'image', data: {} },
  { id: 6, type: 'twitter', data: {} },
  { id: 7, type: 'text', data: {} }
]
```

Each different type has different `view` and quite different logic behind it. In other words - each `type` has its own angular2 `Component`.

So abstract code what I try to achieve is:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
   <item-{{item.type}} [data]="item.data"></item-{{item.type}}>
</div>
```

Of course it will not work.

### Possible solution #1

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
   <item-text *ngIf="item.type === 'text'" [data]="item.data"></item-text>
   <item-image *ngIf="item.type === 'image'" [data]="item.data"></item-image>
   ...
</div>
```

I don't like this solution not only because it looks ugly and I will have to include this line every time I'll add new type but I wonder if this solution is good from performance perspective? I mean if I have 10,000 different types and only 3 items to display. So angular2 will have to remove from DOM 9,999 tags and leave only one for each of 3 items (3 * 9999 remove operations).

### Possible solution #2

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
   <dynamic-component-loader [item]="item"></dynamic-component-loader>
</div>
```

At the moment I don't remember how exactly `DynamicComponentLoader` works (I have tried it in similar problem in angular2 alpha long time ago). But as I remember the code looks like `hack` for me.. For such common task?..

### Angular 1.x thinking

I don't know what I do wrong, maybe the problem is that I still think in `Angular 1`? Using it I would use `ngInclude` or custom directive with template function.

Guys, do you have other solutions how to do it? Don't stick to my two potential solutions, maybe I need to think out of the box and solve this problem completely in different part of my application.. I'm confused. Thanks:)

### EDIT: One more real world example

Let's say your task is to write Facebook with Angular 2. I think you would face same issue trying to display news feed. Each news feed item has it's type (`text`, `event`, `ads`,.. )

Comment: Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468

Comment: If you have a limited number of components just go with your attempt (`*ngIf*)

Comment: yeah, **ngIf** looks good to me, it's the cleanest way, don't know why you say it's ugly. If you want to see something ugly, take a look at the DynamicComponentLoader / ComponentFactoryResolver

Comment: @tibbus good answer :D I saw DCL. I don't see solution with ngIf very ugly but I thought there is more clever way and I thought I think some how wrong solving this task. But if you guys say it's ok - I'm perfectly fine with it. Actually there will be up to 10 different types.

Comment: Have you considered ngSwitch? It's similarly ugly to your solution #1, minus the looping.

Comment: I agree `*ngIf` solution is ugly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you could use "ngComponentOutlet" that came with Angular 4 which creates component dynamically based on the value passed. I havent tested the code though.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <h1>Angular version 4</h1>
    <div *ngFor="let <component name> of <list of component name>">
        <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="<component name>">enter code here</ng-container>
    </div>
  `,
})
```

please refer url for more details : https://netbasal.com/a-taste-from-angular-version-4-50be1c4f3550

Answer (score 7):

This is my solution:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewContainerRef, TemplateRef, ComponentFactoryResolver, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'item',
  template: '',
  styleUrls: ['./item.component.scss']
})
export class ItemComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() type: string;
  @Input() data: any;

  constructor(
    private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private componentLookupService: YourComponentLookUpService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const component = this.componentLookupService.findByType(type);
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);
    // Look at the https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewContainerRef-class.html#!#createComponent-anchor for more information about how to use DI... in the createComponent function.
    const componentRef =this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
    // Or you can then access the newly created component here: this.componentRef.instance
  }

}
```

In your NgFor loop:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
   <item [type]="item.type" [data]="item.data"></item>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd write another component, say `item-flex`:

```
<item-flex [item]="item" *ngFor="let item of items"></item-flex>
```

And `item-flex` could use either `ngSwitch`:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="item.type">
    <item-text *ngSwitchCase="'text'" [data]="item.data"></item-text>
    <item-image *ngSwitchCase="'image'" [data]="item.data"></item-image>
    <span *ngSwitchDefault >UNKNOWN TYPE:{{item.type}}</span>
</div>
```

or the "ugly ifs" (this way you can even get rid of the external tag/div/span that is present in `ngSwitch` solution):

```
<item-text *ngIf="item.type=='text'" [data]="item.data"></item-text>
<item-image *ngIf="item.type=='image'" [data]="item.data"></item-image>
```

Answer (score 2):

My first thought would be to create a directive and use the [Renderer class](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/index/Renderer-class.html) to add the appropriate component conditionally.

```
<div app-item [type]="item.type" [data]="item.data"></div>
```

Directive

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, Renderer,  OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[app-item]'
})
export class ItemDirective implements OnInit {
    @Input('type') type: string;
    @Input('data') data: any[];
    constructor(private el: ElementRef, private r: Renderer) {  }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        switch(this.type){
        case: 'text'
            let self = this.r.createElement( this.el.nativeElement, 'item-text' );
            this.r.setElementAttribute(self, 'data', 'this.data')
            break;
        case: 'image');
            let self = this.r.createElement( this.el.nativeElement, 'item-image'
            this.r.setElementAttribute(self, 'data', 'this.data')

            break;
        // ... so on ...
    }
}
```

You can use more `@Inputs` to pass in parameters and attach them using other `Renderer` methods.

This keeps the view very simple and will not not load modules for items whose tyoes ar not required.

Comment: it will yield <item-text></item-text> instead of a compiled template for item-text